# Telerik push notifications filtering

Tags: c#, json, telerik

Im working on a system that sends push messages automatic when a new item is posted in the system. This goes well. The problem is that i have to do some filtering on software package and profession.

In the first filter block it works but its sends to all the devices that match 1 one of the criteria. What i want (and tried in test 2&3) is that it only sends when someone has the software package AND a certain profession.

The stupid thing of the telerik api is that it just returns a HTTP 400 so debugging is very hard

Hopefully someone could help me with this.

ps. i skipped some irrelevant code/functions in the snippet

```
function sendNotifications(some parameters)
{
    string json = "{";
    //Test code 1 - This works
    json += "\"Filter\": {";
    json += "\"Parameters.softwarePakket\": {\"$in\": [ \"{software_package}\"]},";
    json += "\"Parameters.beroepsGroep\": {\"$in\": [\"{profession1}\", \"{profession2}\"]},";
    json += "\"Parameters.module\": {\"$in\": [\"{module}\"]}},";

    //Test code 2 - This doesn't work
    //json += "\"Filter\": {\"$and\":[{\"Parameters.softwarePakket\":\"{software_package}\"},{\"Parameters.beroepsGroep\":\"{profession1}\"}]}";

    //Test code 3 - And this doesn't work either
    //json += "\"Filter\": \"{\"$and\":[{\"Parameters.softwarePakket\":\"{software_package}\"},{\"Parameters.beroepsGroep\":\"{profession1}\"}]}\"";

    //From here its all fine
    json += "\"Android\": {\"data\": {\"title\": \"{app_title}\",\"message\": \"{message}\",\"color\": \"#ffffff\",\"largeIcon\": \"{icon}\",\"customData\": \"{type}\"}},";
    json += "\"IOS\": {\"aps\": {\"alert\": \"{message}\",\"badge\": \"+1\",\"sound\": \"default\",\"category\": \"{type}\"},\"customData\": \"{type}\"}";
    json += "}";

    json = json.Replace("{type}", type);
    json = json.Replace("{icon}", formatIcon(type));
    json = json.Replace("{message}", genericMessage(type));

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.everlive.com/v1/{app_id}/Push/Notifications");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = json.Length;
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        stream.Write(json);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a comma at the end of the filter string. So the code should be:

```
//Test code 2
json += "\"Filter\": {\"$and\":[{\"Parameters.softwarePakket\":\"{software_package}\"},{\"Parameters.beroepsGroep\":\"{profession1}\"}]},";

//Test code 3
//json += "\"Filter\": \"{\"$and\":[{\"Parameters.softwarePakket\":\"{software_package}\"},{\"Parameters.beroepsGroep\":\"{profession1}\"}]}\",";
```